# compiling windows screensavers on linux

Tags: windows, linux, compiler-construction, screensaver, dosbox

an customer would like to provide to his website visitors an windows screensaver as download. So far so god, but: The screensavers should be generated on the fly with some meta date which needs to be displayed within the screensaver.

I've found some windows tools which can create screensaver files through an UI (http://www.instantstorm.com/download/) but they provide no documented cli interface if neither. The cli interface could be useful when using DOSBox on ubuntu to compile an screensaver file.

The question is how this could be accomplished?

Best,
Stanislav

Comment: Can you embed the metadata as a resource? That way you only have to do the bare minimum linking on linux, or even limit the size of the metadata to 4K or 8K and edit it directly into a pre-built binary. (not sure if the resource section is checksummed?)

Comment: thanks, the main question is, Is out there an windows based screensaver generation program which offers an documented cli?

Answer (score 1):

If it's a recent windows application you probably need to use `wine` instead of `dosbox`, which doesn't really need X if it's a cli app.

Comment: thank you for the tip. The main question is, Is out there an screensaver generation program which offers an documented cli?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can compile windows binaries on Linux, but unless you provide more information, it is impossible to provide more details.

Comment: There are three main alternative questions in here: Do you know an linux program which generates windows screensaver files for cli? Do you know an windows based program which generates windows files from cli? And if yes how this can be used on linux based environment?

Comment: I'm not familiar with windows screensavers (haven't used windows in several years), however depends on what you mean by generate? do you have the c/c++ source code if so you can compile it by either installing msvc 2005 on wine or setup mingw32.

Comment: Setting up mingw and cross compiling for windows is pretty easy, but again, if you don't provide more information, it is impossible to give a precise answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use mingw32 to cross compile executables for windows, though you will need to make your sources acceptable to GCC in order to do this.

However, have you considered the possibility of patching the binary rather than compiling it?  Perhaps things have changed since I last tried it under XP, but I believe strings included in the program or in a resource come through either unchanged or in an accessible encoding which you could easily patch, provided that you kept the length in memory the same (for something null-terminated, you can always make it shorter by placing a null earlier).  Also you might be able to append data to the end of the executable and read that at runtime.

However, if your binary is expected to be signed in some manner, you'd have to do the signing after the modification.